# Clonezilla backup

Tags: backup

I have used Clonezilla to backup my Ubuntu only laptop for years, and have succesfully restored my system from the Clonezilla backup when necessary. So I trust the software. Just out of curiosity, my most recent backup contains 41 objects and the previous one only 29. The previous backup contained harddisk data to xxxxx.aj and the latest to xxxxx.ar. I have not save a lot of data recently, so what could be the reason for this.

Comment: You have to look into your Ubuntu system and search for big files and/or big directories. It can be done with `du` in text mode and easier with `baobab` in graphical mode. Which version of Ubuntu are you running? `baobab` should be available in all current versions.

Comment: You left an important number out right before the word "objects" so your question is meaningless. We don't know if your backup got bigger or smaller.

Comment: @Organic Marble It was 41, sorry about that. I have edited the OP.